# Replacing input{file} by the content fail

Tags: input, epslatex

I have to submit a paper to a journal written in LaTeX. As always, I split my files into different ones. However, the upload is only possible for one file. The different tex files are inserted using the **\input{otherFile}** command. As far as I read, this commend just inserts the whole code of the *otherFile* into the actual position. This is working fine for my normal tex files but for one special case it fails and I don´t know why.

I generated a graphic with gnuplot and exported it as epslatex. Therefore, I get a tex and eps file. The figure is included to the main tex file as:

```
\begin{figure}
\scalebox{scale=0.65}{\input{myGraphic}}
\end{figure}
```

If I replace the content *\input{myGraphic}* with the whole content of the file itself, the compilation fails. I get errors like, undefined *if else*... Does anyone know why this happens?

```
\begin{figure}
\scalebox{scale=0.65}
{
%content of file
.
.
.
%content of file end
}
\end{figure}
```

Any hint is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance, Tobi

PS: The output of the gnuplot file (the *.tex one) is given below:

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolorfalse
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
    \ifx\gptboxheight\undefined%
      \newlength{\gptboxheight}%
      \newlength{\gptboxwidth}%
      \newsavebox{\gptboxtext}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(525,704){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}None}}%
      \put(525,1213){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}}}%
      \put(525,1722){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}}}%
      \put(525,2231){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}}}%
      \put(525,2740){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}Moderate}}%
      \put(525,3248){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}}}%
      \put(525,3757){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}}}%
      \put(525,4266){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}}}%
      \put(525,4775){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}High}}%
      \put(720,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(1560,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$10$}}%
      \put(2400,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$20$}}%
      \put(3240,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$30$}}%
      \put(4079,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$40$}}%
      \put(4919,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$50$}}%
      \put(5759,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$60$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(-377,2739){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}Amount of inserted energy [-]}}}%
      \put(3239,154){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}Time [s]}}%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(4652,1457){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}Energy insertion}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \put(5954,704){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(5954,1213){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$10$}}%
      \put(5954,1722){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$20$}}%
      \put(5954,2231){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$30$}}%
      \put(5954,2740){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$40$}}%
      \put(5954,3248){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$50$}}%
      \put(5954,3757){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$60$}}%
      \put(5954,4266){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$70$}}%
      \put(5954,4775){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$80$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(6459,2739){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}Von Mises Stress [MPa]}}}%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(4652,1216){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}Von Mises Stress}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(7010,704){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(7010,1213){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$75$}}%
      \put(7010,1722){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$150$}}%
      \put(7010,2231){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$225$}}%
      \put(7010,2740){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$300$}}%
      \put(7010,3248){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$375$}}%
      \put(7010,3757){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$450$}}%
      \put(7010,4266){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$525$}}%
      \put(7010,4775){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}$600$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(7647,2739){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}Temperature [$^{\circ} $C]}}}%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(4652,968){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}Temperature}}%
    }%
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{pictures/EPS/PowerControl}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

Comment: it should work unless you have verbatim material in the file, but as you have provided no example, impossible to say in detail whether it should work for your file.

Comment: Can you post the content of the tex file generated by gnuplot?

Comment: Hi David and Michael, I put the output file of gnuplot into my question. Thanks for the feedback. Tobi

Comment: It works for me, after I add this to an empty LaTeX file just including the `graphicx` package and commenting out the line near the bottom which includes `pictures/EPS/PowerControl` (which I don't have, obviously). I'm afraid you may have to provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Move the code from `\begingroup` to `\makeatother` included before `\scalebox` and `\endgroup` after the closing brace

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much. That is the solution. I do not know why we have to go this way around but it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input file has `\makeatletter` which cannot do its work if it's absorbed in the argument to another command, in your case `\scalebox`. The situation changes if the file is input: the category codes are not frozen as they would when absorbed as an argument.

The “solution” is to move the setup part before the `\scalebox`:

```
\begin{figure}
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolorfalse
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
    \ifx\gptboxheight\undefined%
      \newlength{\gptboxheight}%
      \newlength{\gptboxwidth}%
      \newsavebox{\gptboxtext}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
\scalebox{scale=0.65}{% <--- don't forget
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
<THE REST OF THE PICTURE COMMANDS>
  \end{picture}%
}% <--- matching \scalebox{
\endgroup

\end{figure}
```